# How do I apply JNI on a CLASS instead of just random functions brought together?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native, wrapper

I would like to implement an entire Java class via JNI, but I have only been able to find information about implementing methods, not classes themselves.  In every example I've found, the JNI part is always just a bunch of functions.

I have a C++ class that I want to port to Java. I tried following some  tutorials but failed. It doesn't seem to work for classes.

I have run into numerous problems; just one example would be what to do with the constructor of the class.

Comment: this tutorial is good: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html

Answer (score 2):

> Problems are Example: what do i do with the constructor of the class.

You can keep the pointer of the inner Native class in a Java class member with *long* type.

In order to call the constructor of native class in Java class constructor, you can define a separate native method which allocates a native object and keep the resulting pointer in your Java class long type member.

With the example below, you can see a simple Java wrapper class and its JNI implementation which illustrates how to call construct and call inner native pointer:

```
public class JavaClassName {
     private long nHandle;

     protected JavaClassName() {
         nHandle = ConstructNativeHandle();
        }

    public native void SomeMethodJava();

    }
```

and jni implementation:

```
JNIEXPORT long JNICALL Java_packageName_JavaClassName_ConstructNativeHandle
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    NativeClassName * pNativeObject = new NativeClassName();

    return (jlong)pNativeObject;

}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_packageName_JavaClassName_SomeMethodJava
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    jclass c = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    // J is the type signature for long:
    jfieldID fid_handle = env->GetFieldID(c, "nHandle", "J");
    NativeClassName * nativeObject = (NativeClassName *) env->GetLongField(obj, fid_handle);

    nativeObject->SomeMethodNative();

    return;
}
```

Comment: You might want a finaliser or other method to free the native object, or you have a leak.

Comment: @AlanStokes, ofcourse, I just wanted to point out how to call an inner constructor and call a method of this native object

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have been unable to find the information you are looking for is that it does not exist.  JNI is primarily a mechanism for implementing Java native methods in C or C++, and secondarily a mechanism for embedding Java in C or C++.  To serve those purposes it provides means for native code to access and manipulate Java objects, but it was never intended to allow Java classes themselves to be implemented in native code, and it makes no provision for that.

You can create a Java class whose methods are all native, and you can use such a class to wrap your C++ class (instances will each retain a pointer to an instance of the native class, most likely as a Java `long`), but you cannot compile native code into a Java class.

There are tools that can help with this sort of thing.  First on my list to consider would be [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/index.php).